# Electric Field and Potential between two infinite sheets with multiple dielectric mediums

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, dielectric

Suppose we have 2 infinite sheets, one lies on $z = 0$ with potential $V = V_0$ and another at $z = a + b$ with potential $V = 0$. There are two slabs of dielectric material with permittivity $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$. The dielectric interface lies at $z = a$.

Here's my attempt at the question:

Dielectric material between the sheets $\to$ there's no free charge, hence Poisson's equation is reduced to Laplace's equation. Since we have symmetry $\Phi$ is a function only of $z$
$$
\dfrac{d^2}{dz^2}\Phi(z) = 0
$$

$$
\implies \Phi(z) = C_1z + C_2
$$

There are two boundary conditions:

$$
 \Phi(0) = V_0 
$$

$$
 \Phi(a + b) = 0 
$$

Using them, we obtain
$$
\Phi(z) = \dfrac{-V_0}{a + b}z + V_0
$$

When we move on to find the electric field we simply use the relation
$$
\vec{E}(z) = -\nabla\Phi(z) 
$$

$$
\vec{E}(z) = \dfrac{V_0}{a + b}\hat{k}
$$

Intuitively speaking, shouldn't there be a discontinuity in the E-field at $z = a$ due to difference in permittivity of the mediums? If so, what mistake am I making? I figured there is no free charge at all even at the dielectric interface since the dielectrics are continuous. The last part of this problem asks to physically explain why there's a discontinuity in the E-field.

Attempt 2:

We have 2 regions $0 \leq z \leq a$ and $a \leq z \leq a + b$,
The potential must be continuous otherwise we have an infinite electric field which makes no sense.

$$
\mathrm{\Phi}(z) = \begin{cases}
   \displaylines{A_1z + B_1 & 0 \leq z \leq a \\
                 A_2z + B_2 & a \leq z \leq a + b
                }
\end{cases}
$$

3 boundary conditions:
$$
\displaylines{\begin{align} \Phi(0) &= A_1(0) + B_1 = V_0 \\
              \Phi(a + b) &= A_2(a + b) + B_2 = A_2(a) + A_2(b) + B_2 = 0 \\ 
              A_1(a) + B_1 &= A_2(a) + B_2 
              \end{align}}
$$

You end up with 2 equations and 3 unknowns

$$
\displaylines{\begin{align} A_1(a) + V_0 = A_2(a) + B_2 \\ 
                            A_2(a) + A_2(b) + B_2 = 0 \end{align}}
$$

Now I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

The electric field depends on the charge density as a whole, which comprises free **and** bound charge. At the boundary between the two dielectrics, there is - as you said - a discontinuity in the permittivity and therefore a layer of bound surface charge arising from the difference in polarization. $\nabla^2 \Phi$ is not zero everywhere between the two plates.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the change in polarization is the cause for the discontinuity, that makes sense since we're talking about dielectrics and not perfect conductors. How does that affect the math however?

Comment: @Star You have to solve for each region separately and then match the boundary conditions, which requires knowing the bound charge. The most straightforward way would be to start with the electric displacement (whose divergence *isn't* affected by bound charge) and Gauss' Law.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!